# Create an user in Sharepoint and Add to the particular sharepoint group

Tags: javascript, html, online

I need to create user through JavaScript in SharePoint online while registering the user in aspx page using the same data as in the registration form on **clicking** of submit button

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to create new user with EnsureUser method..

```
function ensureUser(accountName)
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/ensureUser('" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "')";
    return $.ajax({       
       url: endpointUrl,   
       type: "POST",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       }
    });
}


var accountName = 'i:0#.f|membership|newuser@yourdomaim.com';
ensureUser(accountName)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('New user created....');   
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log("Error creatign user----" + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```